# Method in WebUserControl is called many times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method in WebUserControl which is called twice in my code once from the Page_load  event of WebUsercontrol (Inside !isPostback) and second in the page_Load event of Page where this WebUserControl is used (again in !ispostback).

But I kept a breakpoint on this method and observe that this is called around 8 times.

This method is called even when I log-In into the application.

I understand that if you AutoEventWireup = "true" then the page_Load method is called twice.

But why this method is called 8 times?

Why this method is called on Login Page?

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: we're gonna have to see your buggy code, mate =)

Comment: The code do not have any bugs, But the code is running many times even  when its not needed like login page.

Comment: You can't say that your code doesn't have any bugs while asking for advice about why a particular event fires 8 times. It's contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

May be your WebUserControl renders again and again like your page is creating postbacks so that method runs many time.